# Community Detection with Louvain in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb, tigergraph, python-arango

I couldn't find a Pregel implementation of the Louvain algorithm for community detection in ArangoDB. I need to compare this algorithm with different solutions in GDBMS, particularly Neo4j and TigerGraph. While there are ready-to-use implementations available for those two.

I'm looking for guidance on how to proceed with ArangoDB.